# Problem installing R4.0 on LInux Mint 19.3

Tags: r, installation, linux-mint, r-4.0.0

I'm trying to install R 4.0 on Linux Mint 19.3 but get the following error message :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
Depends: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable.
```

Can any one please help ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Mint 19.3 is based on Ubuntu 18.04, which is called bionic beaver. You may have used the wrong entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. [You need this one](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/):

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
```

Because `bionic` is the Ubuntu release that fits Mint 19.3.

You need to delete (or comment out with `#`) any other R entries if they exist. If you get errors, check the extra sources file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`.

Comment: Hey Deleet ! 
Thanks a lot for your help, it worked ! 
I had this entry in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file : `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`, I made the change and it's working now !
Am i supposed to "update" `/etc/apt/sources.list` every once in a while (I'm pretty new to Linux...) with a new address?
Thanks again!

Comment: I actually had the same problem as you, figured it out, and posted the solution here. Yes, you go to the CRAN page for the R version (in post above), find the line of code needed for that version of Ubuntu that your version of Mint is based on. Remember to click "accept answer" if you are happy with it.